# Any way to auto-overwrite when copying files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When copying files in Windows 7, is there a button I can hold to skip the overwrite confirmation dialogs? E.g. if I know the files exist in the destination folder and I already know I want to overwrite them all, I'd like to be able to hold Ctrl for copy and then Shift for auto-overwrite (no prompt).

Comment: Maybe you should look into some sort of folder sync software.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't really for syncing, it's just one-off copying from any random location to another.

Answer (score 3):

Open a powershell window and use its copy-item cmdlet with -recurse -force to overwrite. This would be a reasonable workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
xcopy <source> <destination> /S /E /Y
```

That should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's annoying. You could try [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/features.html), which will give you XP's copy/paste overwrite all y/n style.